# How to reference the DOM element knockout creates when foreach binding to an observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

When you click on one of the four buttons in this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/Fe8mT/

```
     [Spades] [Hearts] [Diamonds] [Clubs]
```

knockout will add a new LI item to the UL corresponding to the "suit" of the button.  I would like to know how to reference the newly created LI element in the `self.addCard` handler.

```
            self.addCard = function (data,event) {                    
                var card = event.currentTarget.id; // the button's id (S, H, D, C)        
                self.hand.push(card);
            };
```

I want to add a css class to the LI knockout creates when an item is pushed onto the observableArray. If the [Spades] button was clicked, adding a "spade" to the observableArray, I'll addClass("spades") to the LI; if the [Hearts] button was clicked, I'll addClass("hearts").

Comment: Do you want to also add these classes to the already exiting elements to the list or only to the newly added ones?

Comment: In the actual app, when the observableArray is initially populated with data from the database, the class must be added to each new item as it is added to the array. Then the user may remove some items, or add new ones, and the array will be saved back to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply the classes only to the newly added items then you can use the [`afterAdd` callback on the `foreach`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note_7_postprocessing_or_animating_the_generated_dom_elements) binding:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: hand, afterAdd: afterAdd}" id="hand">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

And in your viewmodel:

```
self.afterAdd = function (element) {
    var li = $(element).filter("li");
    li.addClass(self.getClass(li.text())); // getClass turns "S" to "spades"
}
```

Or you can create a custom binding handler which delegates to the `foreach` and encapsulates your DOM manipulation logic in order to keep your viewmodel "clean".

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/kz6Pg/).

If you want to apply your styles to all the elements (so to the already existing and to the newly added ones) you can use the `afterRender` callback instead of the `afterAdd`.

Or in this case you can just use the `class` binding which removes the jquery dependency and all the DOM manipulation from your viewmodel:

In this case your binding will look like:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: hand" id="hand">
    <li data-bind="text: $data, css: $parent.getType($data)"></li>
</ul>
```

And in your viewmodel you just need a function which returns the class names:

```
self.getType = function (card) {
    if (card == "S") return "spades";
    if (card == "H") return "hearts";
    if (card == "D") return "diamonds";
    if (card == "C") return "clubs";
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/MjpJY/1/).

Comment: Thank you for the excellence of this answer, guiding me in the right direction.